# Image upload field works in django admin but not working in template

Tags: python, django, forms, generics, django-admin

Hi i created a generic form to insert data everything is working fine but image could not upload in template form but when i upload image in admin it works perfectly and image display on template page.

**Here is my code:**

views.py:

```
class ArticleCreate(CreateView):
model = article
fields = ['title', 'cat', 'img', 'disc', 'tags']
```

models.py:

```
class article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   disc = models.TextField(verbose_name="Discription")
   cat = models.ForeignKey(category, verbose_name="Category")
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
   img = models.ImageField(blank=True, verbose_name='Image')
```

Settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Template page:

```
{% for list in data %}
 {{ list.title }}
{% if list.img %}
  {{ list.img.url }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What can i do to upload image with generic form ?

Comment: What's in your form template?

Comment: form template:
{% for field in form %} {{ field.errors }} {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}

{% endfor %}

Comment: Is this not wrapped in form tags?

Comment: See this link after you properly wrap up the fields in a form. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32429092/5189811

Answer (score 8):

In template add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>` it will allow image to get uploaded from template also.

**template form:**

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Answer (score 3):

One more general error is we can forget the request.FILES attribute in views: e.g.

```
form = someModelForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<img src="{% if list.img %}{{ list.img.url }}">
```