# Image upload in CreateView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, image, upload

I have a `CreateView` in my project to post a tweet-like-post. It has a title and content.
It look like this in views.py

```py
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']


    def form_valid(self, form):  # Author for post (required- if no- error)
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And I would like to add `picture-upload` column to make a persons able to upload a picture with the post.

My models.py looks like this

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='タイトル')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='内容')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I already have a `uploaded_pic` folder in my `static` with 777 permision.
Could you please tell me how to add there working `picture-upload` column

Answer (score 0):

```
picture_upload = models.ImageField()
```

If left as is it will upload to MEDIA_ROOT, which is recommended, but if you really want to modify that directory, you can use the `upload_to` property.

```
from django.conf import settings
picture_uploaded = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.STATIC_URL + '/uploaded_pic')
```

Comment: it runs for any valid path you put there, I put that as an example because you said that created a dir under static, but you can use anything or other settings.py configs like MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: thanks, but before that, do you know how to write code like that? I was trying this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423123/django-create-view-image-upload   but it doesnt works.... probably my fault