# Django wont upload images to media directory

Tags: python, django, media

Today I tried to have images in my project and the idea is simple - create news with an image, title, and description.
I wonder why when I set up my media files
So I make my news in this view:

```
class NewsCreate(views.CreateView):
template_name = 'web/create_news.html'
model = News
fields = ('title', 'image', 'description')
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Here is the model:

```
class News(models.Model):
TITLE_MAX_LENGTH = 30
title = models.CharField(
    max_length=TITLE_MAX_LENGTH
)
image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='news/',
    blank=True
)
description = models.TextField()
```

Here is the set-up in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'mediafiles'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Here is the urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include('University_Faculty.web.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I've noticed that when I try to go to none existing URL this happens : [wrong ulr page showing media as a correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEDWg.png)

This is the result in my media folder after 10+ POST requests it shows in the database that it is actually creating the news, but the images won't go anywhere: [no files media folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqpg8.png)

Comment: Write `FileField` in place of `ImageField`, and it's recommended to make the folder `media` instead of `mediafiles`.

Comment: potential duplicate or similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423123/django-create-view-image-upload

Comment: @Sunderam tried that, but still same result

Comment: Problem found I haven't put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag I should've put the template in the question aswell

Answer (score 1):

add this to settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: That is basically(BASE_DIR)already maintained above in `settings.py`,by importing `os` and resolving `parent.parent`, consequently doing the same.

Comment: see here could be a permission issue if code is correct : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73045506/3904109

Answer (score 0):

You need to  correct

> MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

Hope this will work for you.